# newtcolorbox option drop lifted showed not working completely

Tags: environments, tcolorbox, options

I created three environments using the package `tcolorbox`. The option `drop lifted shadow` appears eratically in spite of several compilations under some boxes and not under other ones, without any hint that could indicate the reason why.

Here is the preambule I'm using.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{table,dvipsnames}{xcolor}
%%%
\documentclass[12pt, openright]{scrbook} 
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}  
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}
\usepackage[np]{numprint}
%\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\linespread{1.2}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\newcommand\tsh[1]{\textcolor{NavyBlue}{\textbf{#1}}}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{vobox}{\small}
\AtBeginEnvironment{gbox}{\small}
\AtBeginEnvironment{pbox}{\small}
%\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{makecell}

\newtcolorbox{gbox}{breakable,drop large lifted shadow=black,colback=Mulberry!15!white,colframe=white,rounded corners= all}
\newtcolorbox{pbox}{breakable,colback=teal!15!white,colframe=white,rounded corners= all, drop large lifted shadow=black}
\newtcolorbox{vobox}{breakable, drop large lifted shadow=black,colback=blue!5!white,colframe=white,rounded corners= all}

\title{Tsėhéseamanēō'o \\\vspace{1cm}Langue et culture de la nation Cheyenne}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, urlcolor=magenta, linkcolor=MidnightBlue} 


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\include{chapters/chapter1.tex}
%%%
\include{chapters/chapter29.tex}

\end{document}
```

I add randomly the chapter names. Here are some MWEs with excerpts from these chapters:

```
Comme nous avons évoqué plusieurs termes de la culture cheyenne, voici leur traduction.

\begin{vobox} \begin{tabbing}\hspace{4.5cm}\= \kill
\tsh{héhnove'ohko} \>$\equiv$ le calumet de la paix\\
\tsh{mámaa'e} \>$\equiv$ la coiffe de chef \\
\tsh{ho'honáetȯhoo'e} \>$\equiv$ le tomahawk \\  
\tsh{xamaevee'e} \>$\equiv$ le tipi
\end{tabbing}\end{vobox}
% The very first appearing of a tcolorbox inside the book failes!!
```

```
\addsec{Le verbe: approche générale}

Contrairement aux langues européennes, le cheyenne a un recours fondamental aux verbes qui forment 80\% du lexique, car ces derniers ne se contentent pas de décrire uniquement l'état d'un sujet ou l'action d'un sujet sur un objet, ils incluent aussi des éléments circonstanciels (durée, itération, négation) au sein de formes synthétiques englobant également les pronoms (sujet ou objet, forme obviative ou non).

Tous les verbes appartiennent ainsi à quatre classes:
\begin{gbox}\begin{enumerate}
    \item \textbf{Transitif - (objet) animé:} 
    \begin{tabbing}\hspace{2.5cm} \= \kill 
    \tsh{Návóómo.} \>Je l'ai vu (par ex. son frère).
    \end{tabbing}
    \item \textbf{Transitif - (objet) inanimé:}
    \begin{tabbing}\hspace{2.5cm} \= \kill 
    \tsh{Nápėhévána.} \>Je l'ai réparé (par ex. un objet).
    \end{tabbing}
    \item \textbf{Intransitif - (sujet) animé:} 
    \begin{tabbing}\hspace{2.5cm} \= \kill 
    \tsh{Éhenésone.} \>Elle a eu un enfant.
    \end{tabbing}    
    \item \textbf{Intransitif - (sujet) inanimé:}
    \begin{tabbing}\hspace{2.5cm} \= \kill 
    \tsh{Éhoo'kōho.} \>Il pleut.
    \end{tabbing}    
\end{enumerate}\end{gbox}

\begin{gbox}
\begin{tabbing} \hspace{5cm}\= \kill
\tsh{Névȯome.} \>Tu m'as vu.\\
\tsh{Névȯomȧtse.}\>Je t'ai vu.
\end{tabbing}
\end{gbox}
```

Is it something that happened already to others that using many times the same environments, they wouldn't work properly? I'm adding an image of how it looks like.

[image: Image with erratic options appearance]

Thank you for any help you could provide.

Comment: Try with the key enhanced, in the definition \newtcoclorbox

Comment: Working perfectly well now! Thank you!